# It is possible to get the control flow graph of the native assembly from LLVM?

Tags: llvm

It is possible to get the control flow graph of the llvm assembly.

Is it also possible to get the control flow graph of the native assembly? It would make navigating through the native assembly much easier.

Comment: LLVM works with IR and generates assembly. Not having to work with assembly is, uhm, oversimplifying a bit, is the point of having IR in the first place. What you want is something like [retdec](https://retdec.com).

Comment: @arnt I agree. I am trying to debug simd vectorization that seems to happen by optimization somewhere after IR. My IR is not vectorized but my assembly is (at least if it works).